# Kendo Scheduler issue - content displacement

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using the Kendo scheduler, at the moment using their own mock data, it's working mainly, but the table that it's supposed to represent the days and such, it's all shifted to the left, compressed in the same column. Here is a screenshot of how it looks.

[image]

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

At the moment, I have the mark-up

```
<div id="scheduler"></div>
```

to which I apply `.kendoScheduler()`.

Thank you.

Comment: Your kendoScheduler configuration is just that? ?

Comment: It's the same one used here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index

Comment: And your data is what you expected to have ? Please try to represent your error here, http://jsbin.com/ I dont have enough information to help

Comment: Well, yes. The data is what I expect it to be. But the layout displayed is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to a solution regarding this.

Apparently the problem was the jQuery version. In my instance, I have been using jQuery v2.2.0 and it produced the problem that I mentioned.

When I switched to jQuery v1.12.0 for example, everything worked fine.

Hope that it helps somebody.